# Why does insertNewObjectForEntityForName only return a NSManagedObject?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift

I'm trying to move some RubyMotion code to Swift. So far it works. What I do not understand is
why the following result can't be casted to the Document class:

```
var newObject : NSManagedObject 
  NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Document", inManagedObjectContext:context) 
  as NSManagedObject
```

The insertNewObjectForEntityForName call returns an object of type NSManagedObject. 
But why doesn't insertNewObjectForEntityForName returns an object of type Document as specified by entity.managedObjectClassName  ?

My Entity looks like this:

```
func DocumentEntity () -> NSEntityDescription {

    var entity = NSEntityDescription()
    entity.name = "Document"
    entity.managedObjectClassName = "Document"

    var property = NSAttributeDescription()
    property.name = "title"
    property.attributeType = NSAttributeType.StringAttributeType
    property.optional = false

    entity.properties = [property]

    return entity
}

class Document : NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var title : String
}

model = NSManagedObjectModel()
model.entities = [DocumentEntity()]

var store = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: model)
```

Answer (score 17):

You need to add `@objc(Document)` to your Document class. This is so that Core Data (which is still in Objective-C) can deal with your Swift class.

```
@objc(Document)
class Document : NSManagedObject {
    @NSManaged var title : String
}
```

Then it'll all work:

```
var document = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Document", inManagedObjectContext: context) as Document
```

Will return the right type

Comment: This has been bugging me for awhile but this fixed my issue. Thank you!

Comment: This works, but I wonder if it's really The Right Way, or if @rogergl's way is correct.

Answer (score 5):

The solution is to add the module name to the classname.

e.g.

```
var entity = NSEntityDescription()
entity.name = "Document"
entity.managedObjectClassName = "TestSwift.Document"
```

Comment: This also works in the Xcode CoreData model editor, where "TestSwift" is the name of your project.

Comment: The proper way to handle this is in my response. http://stackoverflow.com/a/24786866/1281407

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you set the class name of you entity in the object model. The format is `YourAppModule.YourClassName`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you try:

```
var document = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Document", inManagedObjectContext: context) as? Document
```

this works for me.

Comment: as? NSManagedObject returns the object but as? Document returns nil

Comment: same thing happens to me with certain Core Data classes.